Server cannot access DNS: ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Good Day.
I already browsed dozens of similar questions and their answers without success.
On my server I can ping for e.g. 8.8.8.8 but not for google.com
With resolve.conf everything seems to look OK, same for netplan.
With sudo resolvectl status I get:
Global
Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: foreign
Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
Link 2 (eno8303)
Current Scopes: none
Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Link 3 (eno8403)
Current Scopes: DNS
Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
DNS Servers: 172.31.102.1 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8  <-- and here there's no CURRENT DNS SERVER
Does this mean that for eno8403 there is no current DNS server? Any idea why? The server is hosted at a Ministry and I have no idea, which ports are open or closed by their hardware firewalls...
cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf gives:
#This is /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
#Do not edit.
#This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
#/etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
#all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
#through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
#different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
#operation for /etc/resolv.conf.
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 172.31.102.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1
#Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search .*

Try to manually overwrite /etc/resolv.conf with
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4


I edited this file before and there is the correct nameserver entry in place. This then can be found in the /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf. Seems to be correct.

Additional question: how is the resolv.conf and the netplan configuration interfering? The nameserver 172.31.102.1, for instance, comes from the netplan, it is not mentioned in the /etc/resolv.conf.

I do not know a lot about netplan. If resolv.conf is correct, I have no idea.

cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 1.1.1.1

It seems good, but combining Google and one.one.one.one seems to be a bizarre idea.

Yes you're right - but this should be for testing only.
